# Beacon - What is the use of different slots ( ibeacon , TLM , URL , UID) available in single beacon tag

Tags: ibeacon, beacon

My beacon tags are broadcasting ibeacon,TLM,URL and UID at a time with different different frequency.
I am not clear about these slots.

I am using beacons for tracking purpose only so don't need to consume all slots data.
What is the simplest way to configure beacon only for detection of his presence only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use either the UID slot or the iBeacon slot for this purpose and turn off the other slots.

Use iBeacon if building an app for iOS and you need fast detection in the background. (iOS is optimized for iBeacon in this mode.)

Eddystone-URL is useful to transmit a website URL on the beacon itself so it can be displayed in nearby Google Chrome browsers configured to detect these beacons.

Eddystone-TLM is useful for knowing the battery level of your beacon (if battery powered) as well as its temperature if that is useful to you.